# Dynamically Summarizing and renaming aggregated columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-manipulation

I have a PySpark data frame(df) which contains 50+ columns including few dynamic columns which could be there or could not be there but they are present in a separate list(Reqd_col). i want to summarize(grouped by fixed column 'region') and aggregated sum or count for only those columns from PySpark data frame(df) which are present in list(Reqd_col) and name of summarized columns should be same as original name of columns not default name which PySpark produces.

Below is an example:-

df- PySpark data frame, consisting of 50+ columns

Reqd_Col = ['Amount', 'Balance', 'Customer'] --> This is a dynamic list which keeps changing but elements inside will be present as a columns in df.

Summarized output should look something like below:-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be a feasibility to identify which are the columns considered for `count` and `sum` or any aggregation.

Have added 2 arrays one will have all the columns which needs to considred for `count` and another for `sum`.

```
columns = ["Region", "Amount", "Balance", "Customer"]
df = spark.createDataFrame([('NAM',100,200,'ABC'),('NAM',300,400,'XYZ')], columns)

sum_cols = ['Amount', 'Balance']
count_cols = ['Customer']

# Using generators to create aggregation column expression 
sum_cols_expr = list([sum(c).alias(c) for c in sum_cols])
count_cols_expr = list([count(c).alias(c) for c in count_cols])

df.groupby('Region').agg(* sum_cols_expr + count_cols_expr).show()

+------+------+-------+--------+
|Region|Amount|Balance|Customer|
+------+------+-------+--------+
|   NAM|   400|    600|       2|
+------+------+-------+--------+
```